# No submit button for searchView Android app

Tags: android, button, searchview

I use searchview in my Android app and ***I would like to add a button that user presses to start the search***. Based on what I read on the Internet, I can use `setSubmitButtonEnabled` to invoke a submit button instead of putting a button in the layout file. Here's my code:

```
public void setSubmitButtonEnabled (boolean enabled) {

}
```

I put my setSubmitButtonEnabled in the menu inflater as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mylist, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

Apparently I am not doing it right because when I launch my app, I don't see any submit button on the screen. What's missing or what's wrong in my code? Is the submit button supposed to appear on the keypad or on the screen? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call

`searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true)`

Why would you create your own version with no body and expect it to do anything?

Comment: BTW guys. Is there any possibility to keep the submit button (small arrow) shown when the soft keyboard is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

For this use

```
searchView=findViewById(R.id.search_box);
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
```

For submit button icon use

```
app:goIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
```

For SearchView default expanded

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```